# Pandas: Converting a datetime (%Y-%d-%m %H:%M) to (%Y-%m-%d %H:%M)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been up and down and round on this topic with examples, etc, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

I have a pandas dataframe, with a field called `Date` where I wish to change the format from Year-Day-Month Hours:Minutes to Year-Month-Day Hours:Minutes. The new field will be `Date2`.
The `Date` field is has it's type being reported as "Object".

So far I've tried variations on the following:

```
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').dt.strftime('%Y-%d-%m %H:%M')

df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

An example date in the `Date` field is `2020-02-12 04:00`
The desired `Date2` output would be `2020-12-02 04:00`

Comment: Try `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').strftime('%Y-%d-%m %H:%M')`?

Comment: Are you sure original date is that unusual year-date-month format? Does `d` go beyond 12? And `m` limited to 12 or less?

Comment: I'm very sure @Parfait - it's pretty annoying!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did and practice the whole procedure in Google Colab. To get all the source code find my [gist](https://gist.github.com/mhhabib/1b408e260a36fc3014181fc395e65767)

```
df['Date2']=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```